# HTML form to Laravel route?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to add search functionality. The functionality itself is working in the controller. I'm just having trouble stitching the search form to the route.

My form

```
<form method="get" action="/search/">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Search" name="name">
    <button title="Search" type="submit" class="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
```

And in my routes

```
Route::get('/search?name={name}', 'ShowPageController@searchShows');
```

Comment: try this:

so replace the below code in your view:

<form method="get" action="{{ route('search')}}">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Search" name="name">
    <button title="Search" type="submit" class="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</form>

in your routes/web.php replace the your code with the code below:

Route::get('/search', 'ShowPageController@searchShows')->name('search');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your route should be

`Route::get('/search', 'ShowPageController@searchShows');`

and in your controller you should get the value of the `name` query string key pair by doing the following

```
public function searchShows(Request $request) 
{ 
    $name = $request->query('name');

    ....
}
```

Also, I would consider aliasing your route e.g.

`Route::get('/search', 'ShowPageController@searchShows')->name('search');`

Then in your form you can just do

```
<form method="get" action="{{ route('search') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

enter code here`1. Way

```
Route::get('/search/{name?}', 'ShowPageController@searchShows');
```

if you put ? in the end it will be optional parameter if not it will now be.

2. Way
   you don't have to put it your route 
   route :

> ```
>   Route::get('/search', 'ShowPageController@searchShows');
> ```

inside of your controller :

```
function searchShows(Request $request) {
     $searchparams = $request->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so replace your code with the below code in your view:

```
<form method="get" action="{{ route('search')}}">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Search" name="name">
    <button title="Search" type="submit" class="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

in your routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/search', 'ShowPageController@searchShows')->name('search');
```

and then in your controller:

```
public function searchShows(Request $request) 
{ 
    $s_query = $request->name;
    // perform operation now
}
```